# Django template divisible by list length

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use Django's template language to do some calculations:

```
{%  if forloop.counter|divisibleby:table.1|length %}
```

but I want the `divisibleby` to take `table.1|length` as an argument rather than only `table.1` like it seems to do by default. (table.1 is a `list`)

Any way to do this besides passing the length from a view?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like using the template tag [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

```
{% with table_length=table.1|length %}
    {%  if forloop.counter|divisibleby:table_length %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```